# udp hole punch and port restricted cone NAT，

Tags: nat, hole-punching

I would like to understand how udp hole punching works when two hosts each behind the port restricted cone NAT establish connection.

As I understood, it happens in several stages and involves three hosts.

Host A and host B are behind the port restricted cone NAT.

Host C is a server that can receive packets from the hosts A and B.

1. A sends a packet to C.
2. C receives packet from A and determines A's external address:port pair
3. B sends a packet to C.
4. C receives packet from B and determines B's external address:port pair
5. C sends the external address:port of B to A
6. C sends the external address:port of A to B
7. A sends packet_1 to B's external address
8. B sends packet_2 to A's external address

But I can't do it。it's the window，Who can tell me why?

[image]

Comment: Not a good question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

in the golang
Only

net.ListenUDP() 's *UDPConn* can use the method **WriteToUDP（）**

net.DialUDP 's *UDPConn* can't //

Sorry my English is very poor。

I think maybe nobody can read this。

囧TZ